# How to create a preAuthorized PayIn with the MangoPay PHP SDK?

Tags: php

I'm currently working on a project with the MangoPay api (with PHP SDK) and I have some trouble with the PaymentDetails. The function below generate this key (when I call the MangoPay Create method on my PayIn object) :

```
payins_stdclass-direct_create
```

instead of :

```
payins_preauthorized-direct_create
```

The function I'm using :

```
<?php
private function createAuthorizationPayIn($authorization, $fees)
{       
     $payIn = new MangoPay\PayIn();

     $payIn->CreditedWalletId = $this->adminWalletId;        
     $payIn->AuthorId = $this->adminUserId;

     $payIn->PaymentType = "PREAUTHORIZED";
     $PayIn->PaymentDetails = new MangoPay\PayInPaymentDetailsPreAuthorized();
     $payIn->PaymentDetails->PreauthorizationId = $authorization->Id;

     $payIn->DebitedFunds = new MangoPay\Money();
     $payIn->DebitedFunds->Currency = $authorization->DebitedFunds->Currency;
     $payIn->DebitedFunds->Amount = $authorization->DebitedFunds->Amount;

     $payIn->CreditedFunds = new MangoPay\Money();
     $payIn->CreditedFunds->Currency = $authorization->DebitedFunds->Currency;
     $payIn->CreditedFunds->Amount = $authorization->DebitedFunds->Amount;

     $payIn->Fees = $fees;

     $payIn->ExecutionType = "DIRECT";
     $payIn->ExecutionDetails = new MangoPay\PayInExecutionDetailsDirect();
     $payIn->ExecutionDetails->SecureMode = "DEFAULT";
     $payIn->ExecutionDetails->SecureModeReturnURL = "https://website.com";

     $payIn = $this->mangoPayApi->PayIns->Create($payIn);

     $authorization->payinId = $payIn->Id;
     $authorization = $this->mangoPayApi->CardPreAuthorizations->Update($authorization);

     return $payIn;
}
```

How can I create the right PaymentDetails object to create a preAuthorized PayIn ?

Comment: Could you help me get start with mangopay into a wordpress website?